# Android ScrollView QuickAction effect

Tags: android, animation, scrollview, quickaction

I need some help, i want the android scrollview animation effect....
Basically when the someone click on the textview of linearlayout in scrollview another horizontal view should come in.

Here is the pic....[image]

Comment: Try [this](http://www.ziddu.com/download/17219951/lorensiuswlt-NewQuickAction-v1.0.0-0-g5986f5c.zip.html) once

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it would come over the previous view...so thats an issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is setup ontouch() on the textview. once you touch it then you would make the layout visible with setVisiblity(). you could even add in a animation to make it more professional.

You would probably get a bug if you didnt make every other view GONE, when you touch a new textview.

I like this idea and I might work around with it myself!

Good Luck